# push forward of differential form/ integration over fiber

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-forms, smooth-manifolds

It is elementary that differential forms can be pulled back via a smooth map between manifolds. However, I was reading a paper and came across a construction about push forward of a differential form via a submersion which I didn't fully understand.

The paper pointed to *Differential Forms in Algebraic Topology* by Bott and Tu for reference. However, since I have little background in algebraic topology, I would like to know if anyone can show me a more detailed explanation, or point me to some references.

Below is the construction as described in the paper:

> If $f: X\rightarrow Y$ is a submersion from an oriented manifold of dimension $n$ to an oriented manifold of dimension $m \leq n$. Then the fibers are manifolds of dimension $r=n-m$.

So far this is OK, and it continues:

> Integration over the fibers gives a map $f_*: D^p(X)\rightarrow D^{p-r}(Y)$ defined as follows.
>
> Any $p$-form $\phi$ on $X$ with compact support can be written $\phi = \psi \wedge f^*\omega$, where $\psi$ is an $r$-form with compact support on $X$ and $\omega$ is a $(p-r)$-form on $Y$. To see this, use a partition of unity to write $\phi$ as a sum of forms with support in a coordinate neighborhood, and in local coordinates the decomposition becomes obvious.
>
> We can then consider $f_*\psi$ on $Y$ with compact support defined by $f_*\psi (y)=\int_{f^{-1}(y)} \psi$ and define $f_*\phi = f_* \psi \wedge \omega$.

What I didn't understand is how the $p$-form $\phi$ on $X$ can be decomposed as $\psi \wedge f^*\omega$. (Even though it says it's obvious in local coordinates...)
Is this decomposition unique? If not, then the push forward $f_* \phi$ better not depend on the decomposition..?

Comment: Using a partition of unity, you can reduce the statement to the one correspinding to forms $\phi$ with support contained in an open set which is a product, using the local form of a submersion.

Comment: Actually, it seems to me that the form $\phi$ can not always be decomposed in the way that is stated in your citation of the paper, not even in the 'standard' case of a projection of Euclidean spaces. 
E.g. consider the projection $$f:\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3: (x,y_1,y_2,y_3)\mapsto (y_1,y_2,y_3).$$
The 2-form $dx \wedge dy_1 + dy_2 \wedge dy_3$ can not be written in the form $\psi\wedge f^*\omega$ with $\psi$ and $\omega$ both 1-forms.

Comment: @Stefan Your form does not have compact support, contrary to what is assumed in the paper.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Please correct me if I am wrong, but I don't think compact support in StefanvanderLugt counter-example is the (main?) reason. If we replace R by [0,1] then StefanvanderLugt's counter-example would work. My impression is that the OP's claim "every $p$-form on X can be decomposed as $\psi\wedge f^*\omega$ for $r$-form $\psi$ on X, $(p-r)$-form on $Y$" is not correct, if not I would very much like to see the proof using paritions of unity, which I think would lead to StefanvanderLugt's counter-example.

Answer (score 5):

The decomposition is not unique, because we can replace $\psi \wedge f^{\ast} \omega$ with $(f^{\ast}(g) \psi) \wedge f^{\ast} (g^{-1} \omega)$ where $g$ is some smooth function $Y \to \mathbb{R}_{>0}$. Of course, this doesn't effect the pushforward, since $\int_{f^{-1}(y)} f^{\ast}(g) \psi = g(y) \int_{f^{-1}(y)} f^{\ast}(g)$ and then $\left( \int_{f^{-1}(y)} f^{\ast}(g) \psi ) (g^{-1} \omega) \right)= g(y) g(y)^{-1} \omega = \omega$. More generally, if $\phi = \alpha \wedge f^{\ast}(\beta \wedge \gamma \wedge \delta)$ with $\alpha$ an $r-k$ form, $\beta$ and $\gamma$ $k$-forms and $\delta$ a $p-r-k$ form, then $\phi = (\alpha \wedge f^{\ast} \beta) \wedge f^{\ast}(\gamma \wedge \delta) = (-1)^k (\alpha \wedge f^{\ast} \gamma) \wedge f^{\ast}(\beta \wedge \delta)$ are two such factorizations.

I think the simplest way to prove indepedence of the decomposition is to describe the pushforward in terms of its integrals. For $\phi$ any compactly supported $p$-form on $X$, and $B$ any embedding of a closed $(p-r)$-dimensional ball into $Y$, we have $\int_B f_{\ast} \phi = \int_{f^{-1}(B)} \phi$ (using Fubini). Since a $(p-r)$-form is defined by its integrals over all $(p-r)$-dimensional balls, this proves uniqueness of such a $f_{\ast} \phi$ (but not existence, use Bott and Tu's argument for that.)

Comment: Hi David! In the second paragraph, every time you say $p$, I think you mean $p-r$, if you want to be consistent with the OP.

Comment: Thanks! Fixed, I think. @HughThomas

Answer (score 0):

For the record: I am now using the following reformulation of the definition of fiber-wise integration, where a unique decomposition appears. I will formulate it for fiber-bundles:

Let $\pi: E\to B$ be a fiber bundle with fiber $F$, and let $\omega\in\Omega^m(E)$.
Let $VE:=\ker(d\pi)\subset TE$ be the *vertical subbundle*.
Suppose that $HE\subset TE$ is a *horizont subbundle*; that is, $TE=VE\oplus HE$.
Given $b\in B$, let $U\subset B$ be a coordinate neighborhood of $b$.
We denote the coordinate functions by $y^i:U\to \mathbb{R}$, $i\in\{1,\dotsc,n\}$.
Pullbacks along $\pi$ of the coordinate forms $d y^I = d y^{i_1} \dotsb d y^{i_k}$ for ordered multiindices $I=\{i_1<\dotsb < i_k\}\subset \{1,\dotsc,m\}$ form a basis of $\Lambda^k_p(HE^*)$ for each $p\in\pi^{-1}(U)$.
Since $\Lambda^m_p(T^*E) = \oplus_{i+j=m}\Lambda^i_p(VE^*)\wedge\Lambda^j_p(HE^*)$, there *exists a unique* $(\omega_I)_p\in\Lambda^k_p(VE^*)$ such that
$$
     \omega_p = \sum_I (\omega_I)_p \wedge \pi^*(d y^I)_p.\tag{1}
$$
Since $\omega_I$ are coefficients of a smooth form with respect to a smooth basis, we obtain smooth sections $\omega_I\in\Omega^k(VE^*|_{\pi^{-1}(U)})$ for all $I\subset\{1,\dotsc,m\}$.

Let $\iota_b: F\hookrightarrow E$ be an inclusion identifying $F\simeq \pi^{-1}(b)$.
If $F$ is oriented and $\iota_b^*(\omega_I)$ integrable, we can define
$$
 \Bigl(\int_F \omega\Bigr)_b = \sum_I \Bigl(\int_F \iota_b^*(\omega_I)\Bigr)\wedge (dy^I)_b.\tag{2}
$$
The integral is independent of $\iota_b$ since it is invariant on diffeomorphism (we assume that $\pi^{-1}(b)$ is oriented and $\iota_b$ orientation preserving).
Therefore, for fixed $b$, we can omit writing $\iota_b$ and consider $\omega_I\in \Omega^k(F)$.

By construction, $\omega_I$ depends on the choice of $HE_p$ for all $p\in\pi^{-1}(b)$ and also on the choice of the coordinates $y$ (more specifically, on the coordinate 1-forms $d y^i$ at $b$).

Giving $HE|_{\pi^{-1}(U)}$ is equivalent to giving a trivialization $\psi\colon F\times U \to E|_{U}$; the correspondence is given by setting $\psi(\xi,y) = (\psi^1_{y^1}\circ\dotsb\circ\psi^m_{y^m})(\xi)$, where $\psi_t^k$ is the time-$t$ flow of the horizontal lift of the coordinate vector field $\partial_{y_k}$ (the flows exist for all $y$ if we assume that $\pi$ is proper; however, we do not need this for the definition of (2) as we can always shrink the neighborhod around $b$)

Suppose that $\psi$ and $\psi^\prime$ are two different trivializations of $E|_{U}$.
Let $\phi= (\psi \circ \psi^{\prime -1})|_{F\times\{b\}}: F\to F$ be the transition function.
The definition of $\omega_I$ implies $\omega^\prime_I = \phi^*(\omega_I)$.
The invariance of the integral on diffeomorphisms then implies that (2) is independent of $HE$ (we assume again that $\phi$ is orientation preserving, e.g., that $E$ is an oriented fiber bundle).

As for the independence of coordinates, let $y^\prime = y^\prime(y)$ be another coordinate system on $U$.
The definition of $\omega_I$ gives $\omega^\prime_I = \sum_J \frac{\partial y^{J}}{\partial y^{\prime I}} \omega_J$, where the derivatives depend on $b\in U$ only.
Plugging this in (2) and noting that $d y^{J} = \sum_I \frac{\partial y^{J}}{\partial y^{\prime I}} d y^{\prime I}$, we obtain the independence of (2) of coordinates.