# Co-area formula in simple case

Tags: measure-theory, multiple-integral

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^d\to \mathbb{R}$ be a Lipschitz function on $\mathbb{R}^d$.

The co-area formula states that for all measurable function $\phi$ we have
$\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \phi \|\nabla f\| dx=\int_{\mathbb{R}}dy\int_{f^{-1}(y)} \phi(x) dH_{n-1}(s)ds
 $ where $H_{n-1}$ is (n-1) Hausdorff measure.

Is there an easy proof of such a result when $f$ is smooth ? Do you get any additional information (for instance continuity with respect to $y$ of $\int_{f^{-1}(y)} \phi(x) dH_{n-1}(s)ds$ if $\phi$ is continuous)  ?

I am in fact interested in the case where $f$ is smooth and striclty convex with a unique minimum.

Comment: When $f$ is smooth and a submersion (i.e., has rank $1$ everywhere), then this is the standard integration-over-the-fiber mapping for a fiber bundle, which is proved easily locally. It's just Fubini's Theorem In your case, there is an isolated critical point, so you just remove that and apply this notion.

Comment: Thank you, I think I can roughly see how it comes down to use Fubini. Do you know a reference (if possible, without the extension of this result to Riemannian manifold, I am really not familial with the terminology)

Comment: Searching this site for *integration over the fiber* will give you some results, e.g., [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1435998/push-forward-of-differential-form-integration-over-fiber). Bott/Tu *Differential Forms in Algebraic Topology* is a standard source. You really do need to do it in the context of differential forms, unfortunately, as they are the natural object to integrate. But, yes, it holds in the setting of manifolds. The other standard reference would be Federer's *Geometric Measure Theory*, which is challenging to read, but excellent to find results.

Comment: Using the point of view of differential form, i guess the co-area formula is not exactly stated as above, i.e not with the Haussdorff measure, but with an other measure. I guess it is standard that both measure coicinde in the smooth case ?

Comment: I think [this note](https://www3.nd.edu/~lnicolae/Coarea.pdf) will answer most of your questions.

Comment: I think it's precisely what i was looking for. Thank you very much.