# Change of variable formula for multivariate integral with constrain

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus, change-of-variable

Suppose $g: \mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}$ is $C^{1}$ and satisfies $\nabla g(x) \neq 0$ for every $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$. Let $E \in \mathbb{R}$ be fixed. I want to find an explicit expression for the integral:
$$\int_{g(x) = E}f(x)dx,$$
provided the integral exists.

I sketched some calculations, but I am not completely sure if it is correct. There are some steps I am not still very convinced. My idea is the following. Let $\phi: \mathbb{R}^{n}\to U\subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ be a change of variable transformation (diffeomorphism) given by:
$$\phi(x) = (\phi_{1}(x),\phi_{2}(x),...,\phi_{n}(x)) \tag{1}\label{1}$$
where I choose $\phi_{1}(x) = g(x)$ and, for each $i=2,...,n$, $\phi_{i}: \mathbb{R}^{n} \to \mathbb{R}$ are $C^{1}$ functions such that the change of variables $\phi$ is orthogonal, in the sense that  $\langle \nabla \phi_{i}(x),\nabla\phi_{j}(x)\rangle = 0$ for every $i\neq j$.

Consider the region:
$$R = \{y = (y_{1},...,y_{n}) \in \mathbb{R}^{n}: y_{1} = E\}\tag{2}\label{2}$$
so we have:
$$\{x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}: g(x) = E\} = \phi^{-1}(R) = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}: \phi_{1}(x) = g(x) = E\}.$$
Using the change of variables formula, we obtain:
$$\int_{g(x) = E}f(x) dx = \int_{R}f(\phi^{-1}(y))\frac{1}{|\det D\phi(\phi^{-1}(y))|}dy = \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}f(E,y_{2},...,y_{n})\frac{1}{\|\nabla g(E,y_{2},...,y_{n})\|}d\Sigma_{E}$$
where $\|x\| = \sqrt{x_{1}+\cdots +x_{n}^{2}}$ is the usual Euclidean norm and:
$$d\Sigma_{E} = \frac{dy_{2}\cdots dy_{n}}{\prod_{i=2}^{n}\|(\nabla\phi_{i})(E,y_{2},...,y_{n})\|}$$

First of all, I would like to know if my reasoning and formula are correct. If so: Can I always find a change of variable $\phi$ which is orthogonal and has one of its components, say, $\phi_{1} = g$ as I did? I am not entirely convinced about it.

Answer (score 1):

Look up the closely-related **Co-Area Formula** for integration over a *family* of submanifolds. You have outlined the key steps in a proof of it. Your ideas  work locally ( if you abandon the assumption that all your local coordinate variables are orthogonal). The global proof can be patched together with a **partition of unit**y.

[Co-area formula in simple case](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4351837/co-area-formula-in-simple-case)

P.S. Your question is somewhat ambiguous because you have not  specified  explicitly that you are integrating over the hypersurface with respect to the canonically induced co-dimension one Hausdorff  measure.